# How to get intersection of objects as lists in lists contain these objects of class?

Tags: c#, list, comparison, ienumerable, intersection

My lists:

```
List<ArtistAndTags> List1 = new List<ArtistAndTags>(); //Contains about 100 elements.
List<ArtistAndTags> List2 = new List<ArtistAndTags>(); //Contains about 70 elements.
```

My class:

```
public class ArtistAndTags
   {
       public string ArtistName { get; set; }
       public List<string> Tags = new List<string>(); //Compare with this list.
   }
```

I should to get `ArtistName` of each `ArtistAndTags` between `ArtistAndTags` lists which contain intersection of any elements in `Tags`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        List<ArtistAndTags> List1 = new List<ArtistAndTags>(); 
        List<ArtistAndTags> List2 = new List<ArtistAndTags>();

        var intersectedList = new List<ArtistAndTags>();

        foreach (var item1 in List1)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in List2)
            {
                if (item2.Tags.Intersect(item1.Tags).Any()))
                {
                    intersectedList.Add(item1);
                    intersectedList.Add(item2);
                }
            }
        }

        var result = intersectedList.Select(x => x.ArtistName).ToList();
```

Comment: Big thanks! So I've already solved it with `foreach`, but your `Select(x => x.ArtistName)` really helps me.